# How access axios response in sweetalert2 confirm dialog

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I probably don't understand promises in full even after reading https://gist.github.com/domenic/3889970, I need to access response from axios in sweetalert confirmation result.

this is my code

```
axios
    .post("/posts", this.formData)
    .then(response => {
        if (typeof response.data.callback !== "undefined") {
            toastr.info("Created");
            swal.fire({
                title: "Success!",
                text: "you created new post",
                type: "success",
                showConfirmButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: "Close this",
                allowOutsideClick: false
            }).then(result => {
                if (result.value) {
                    window.location.replace(response.data.callback);
                }
            });;
        } else {
            toastr.error("Can't process this request");
        }
        this.formLoading = false;
    })
```

the response is undefined, i think i don't understand how scopes work in js

Comment: Looks about right. Any errors in dev tools console? What does `response.data.callback` return? Is the success alert showing? If so what happens when you confirm it? More debugging details would help

Comment: returned `callback` is the url to redirect to after i click confirm swal. but 'data' on response object is undefined

Comment: So rollback to what does `response` look like. It should be your data from server parsed to an object

Comment: I don't follow your suggestion, my problem is that response in the second promise is undefined, so to rephrase my question how do I pass the response returned by axios to sweetalert² promise?

Comment: It shouldn't be. The internal `then()` is within the scope of the outer `then()` and therefore `response` is in scope. I'm just trying to understand what `response` from outer then looks like

Comment: Or how can I redirect to url returned by axios in the response.data.callback object after and only after confirming sweetalert² ?

Comment: It should work IF you are reading the properties of that response object properly. Show what `console.log(JSON.stringify(response))` outputs in console

Comment: AFK now but it is more or less response.data contains this {"callback":"http://site.test/post/124"}

Comment: no it is response.data.callback; @charlietfl the issue here is not how far deep i go into response object as response is undefined in the swall promise an this is my problem.
the error is `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`

Comment: Your code works fine in this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/6z2ykpnz73?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue). It seems your question is missing something relevant to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example you can mirror.. It takes a URL which was received from a successful API call (the URL is in the API response), and then sends another request... this should demonstrate to you that you can do whatever you want there... kick off a different function... literally, *anything you want to do, you can do in that * `.then(...)` block..

---

[CodeSandbox example (updated with chained alerts and API calls)](https://codesandbox.io/s/wnxlyp1kqw)

***EDIT:*** updated my answer to show how you can use the data you retrieve from the API calls....

[image: screenshot of api data being used]

---

```
// Modal.vue component - holds the SweetAlert2

<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="swal();">CLICK ME TO LOAD API DATA USING SWEETALERT2</button>
    <div v-if="name != ''">
      <p>Name: {{ name }}</p>
    </div>
    <div v-if="homeworld != ''">
      <p>Homeworld: {{ homeworld }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      name: "",
      homeworld: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    swal() {
      let self = this;
      this.$swal
        .fire({
          title: "Click OK to load from: https://swapi.co/api/people/1/",
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonText: "OK",
          showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
          preConfirm: () => {
            return this.$axios
              .get("https://swapi.co/api/people/1/")
              .then(response => {
                if (response.status != 200) {
                  throw new Error("Something went wrong");
                }
                return response.data;
              })
              .catch(error => {
                this.$swal.showValidationMessage(`Request failed: ${error}`);
              });
          },
          allowOutsideClick: () => !this.$swal.isLoading()
        })
        .then(result => {
          if (result.value) {
            let v = result.value;
            self.name = v.name;
            this.$swal
              .fire({
                title: "Click Ok to redirect to another API call",
                text: `Going to (name:)"${v.name}"'s homeworld URL at: "${
                  v.homeworld
                }"`,
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: "OK",
                showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
                preConfirm: () => {
                  return this.$axios
                    .get(v.homeworld)
                    .then(response => {
                      if (response.status != 200) {
                        throw new Error("Something went wrong");
                      }
                      return response.data;
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                      this.$swal.showValidationMessage(
                        `Request failed: ${error}`
                      );
                    });
                },
                allowOutsideClick: () => !this.$swal.isLoading()
              })
              .then(res => {
                if (res.value) {
                  self.homeworld = res.value.name;
                  this.$swal.fire({
                    title: "Homeworld",
                    text: JSON.stringify(res.value)
                  });
                }
              });
          }
        });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for your example i think my sequence is different - my store method would display success method after and only after successful response from the server with callback and then redirect after click on  confirm button

Comment: Thats exactly what mine is doing. It only displays the data after a successful response.  Check out the comments I put in my answer. Basically, it's all about chaining the `swal` - as you can see, all you do is create new `swal`'s after each step.

Comment: @dascorp see my updated answer, and updated link - this shows you how to chain the `swal`'s .... not sure what else you're looking for here.

Comment: @dascorp updated it again to show how you can use the data from the API inside of your HTML/component... is this what you're looking for??

Answer (score 0):

I read your comment and you said that callback is a url, i've used axios and sweetalert before, it seems that you need to pass the "callback" in json format. Have you done it? If not, this is an example using Laravel. Sorry for my english.

Controller.php

```
...
if(isAjax){
   return response()->json(['status'=>'info','messages'=>'Winter is coming!','rheader'=>'Warning!']);
}
...
```

View (Vue that uses Sweetalert) , general sweetalert should work too

```
...
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
axios.post("{{route('someroute')}}",{id:xid}) //you can ignore this, this is just passing id to the route
.then(response => {
  this.$swal(response.data.rheader, ""+response.data.messages+"", response.data.status);
  if(response.data.status=="success"){
    $("#something")).hide();
  }
})
.catch(e => {
  this.$swal("Warning", ""+e.response.data.messages+"", "warning");
});
...
```

Hope it'll help someone :)